# cURL Put Request

Tags: url, curl, parse-platform, put, objectid

I very stupidly put urls for objectIds on Parse.com.

Rather than going back to the beginning and replacing the objectIds with parse generated strings, is there a way to alter rows on the database using a PUT request such as:

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: blahblahblah" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: blahblahblah" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"lol" : "cat"}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TRProduct/http://www.a.com/pclick.php?p=757
```

An example of the row in JSON is:

```
{ objectId: http://www.a.com/pclick.php?p=757,
  name: "cat",
  info: "has cheezburger" }
```

As you can see, the object Id appended to the url doesn't make much sense when being parsed by parsed.com. I've tried escaping the special characters and URL encoding the string but to no avail.

Is there any dirty request I can do instead? Otherwise I will just have to spend the hours it will take to replace the data.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but let me be clear :

you want to change all your `objectids` because they're URLs and not actual parse-generated object ids?

I'd say the simplest way is to write a cloud method (or a background job that you'll run manually or anything else really) that just select all of your rows, and re-inserts them without setting a specific `objectId`. Parse should generate it for you.

Because it'll probably be a loop make sure to check the timestamps to not re-insert the newly created rows indefinitly. Timestamps should work, or something gimmicky like checking if the objectId starts with `http:`, then change it, otherwise skip it.

Though now that I think of it, I always thought `objectId` was readonly and I'm surprised you were able to change it.

So yeah, write a method that scans the database and copies all the rows without setting an objectId. Don't forget to delete the original rows. And because I suggested you to do that, export your database first.

if you have more than 1000 rows per class, you'll need a bit more work because queries can only fetch 1000 at a time, and then you'll need to play with the -`skip`, but we'll come back to that if you need it.

Comment: I can re-upload the data. If you import the data you can set the object Id yourself. I can therefore edit the data set but this will take a long time as it's at the end of a huge pipe line. The question was more relating to whether I can use a put request for an object id that looks like that

Comment: It won't take long if you write code to do it for you now, would it? ^^
I'm not very experienced though, so i've actually never heard of "put requests". Sorry I couldn't help more !

Comment: True, but I'm only allowed one background job and it's currently doing a lot of things :(

Comment: Well that's a bummer. :D haha
You could use the JSON export of your table and write code that replaces the texts of all the objectid and replaces them with auto-generated strings that aren't urls. It wouldn't be parse ones, but it'd still be better than urls.

Comment: or you could add your own custom ID column with simple incrementing id's, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, and that'd be easy to edit online.

Comment: Actually a combination of those things. I could export the dataset, use sublime replace 'objectId' with 'url' and re-import (then parse will generate the ids like normal). It's a workaround though as it doesn't solve my PUT request question :(. I wonder if it is at all possible. I'm going to try a URI encode of the id and see if that works...

Comment: Yeah at least if your problem is solved that's a good thing, but maybe someone will clarify the put request for you soon enough here ):